# How to add theme to wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I downloaded the theme from w3layout.com. I installed wordpress and wampserver on my laptop. When i tried to uploaded downloaded theme to wordpress for further editing and customization it simply failed and showed following message.

**"The package could not be installed. The theme is missing the style.css stylesheet.
Theme install failed."**

link of the template - https://w3layouts.com/exchange-education-a-education-category-flat-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/

please help me to solve this problem as its very easy to do editing / customization with wordpress than doing it manually.

Thank you

Comment: did you unzip it in its own folder in the wp-content/themes folder?

Comment: tried ...not working

Comment: ok, in in that new theme folder you see a style.css?

Comment: I think that is a Template and NOT a Theme! A Theme come with many templates, wordpress. Not is equal Common Template at to Wordpress Template!

Comment: You can purchase many themes on https://themeforest.net/category/wordpress.

Comment: @Omnisite yes i can see it

Answer (score 0):

Theme and Templates are not the same.

If you download a Theme from [Wordpress Theme's Repo](https://wordpress.org/themes/) Then you will be able to simply unzip the file in the `/themes/`directory and activate it within the WP-Admin Dashboard.

A Template is simply a post or page `template` which is within a given theme.

The directory of a theme can vary but it could be located within the root of the theme or within a common `/template/` directory.

Sorry if this does not help!